# how to securely publish live stream to Adobe Flash Media Server

Tags: flash, security, media, publish

I want to make sure that only authenticated users are publishing streams to my Adobe Flash Media Server.

Ideally I would like to limit the IPs which are allowed to publish streams to the server.

I read about the Adobe Authentication Plugin, but apparently it is broken since it works only for Adobe Flash Media Live Enconder. It doesn't secure the server for other encoders that publish streams.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**User auth**

Option 1: You could try to use the Flash Media Server Authentication Add-in that you get when you get the flash media live encoder:

https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=fmle3

Option 2: You could also take a look at server side actionscripting. You can pass extra paramters when calling the connect function (client side) and then verify them with the application.onConnect function (server side).

**IP block**

Option 1: General IP Blocking can be done in the Flash Media Server config. Open the Adaptor.xml in your conf/-Folder and change the Allow/Deny entries.

Here's the documentation:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/configadmin/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d119f2926583-7ffb.html

Option 2: Server side actionscript provides you a more fine grained access control. Use the above mentioned application.onConnection function and verify the IP adress by accessing it with Client.ip property.

Docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashMediaServer/3.5_SS_ASD/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a11afc95e-7ec3.html

Comment: User auth - As far as I'm aware, FM server authentication add-in is broken, considering that it authenticates only Adobe FMLE. If I am to publish a stream with some other encoder, it passes this "protection". So it is only false sense of security.

Comment: IP blocking - both publishing and viewing RTMP steams is done on port 1935. So I can't just allow/deny IP connections. I want to block everyone except me only for "publishing" a stream

Comment: Regarding server-side actionscript - you are correct, but I am using a ready-made live service. If I am to write my own live service, I would have this in mind (and it will definitely work), but if I want to use ready-made server-side application provided by Adobe, I am lost.

Comment: Yeah, if you use the same server for publishing and delivery you can't do a global IP block. We usually use a dedicated server for publishing and a CDN for the actually delivery to users.

Comment: I am not aware of the auth add-in being broken. As far as I know it worked at least up to FMS 3.5, but it's not an option for you in any case if you got no access to the server or system files, since you addin installs into the FMS folder, without FMS likely won't require auth.

Comment: Finally, if you got no access to FMS config folders and can't install your own scripts I don't see a way for you to control publishing yourself. You gotta ask your hosting company what methods they offer. They must have some kind of method, a configuration that's as open as you describes it makes no sense outside of some special setups.